# How to change class of button if it's id exists as key of local storage object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I am trying to change the class of a button if it's id appears in a local storage object I am currently using the following. The local storage objects are stored as json objects as;

```
{"latlng":"(50.000000, -50.00000)","address":"1235 any street","image":"http://localhost/images/image.jpg","id":123456789}


window.addEventListener("load", changeButton, false);

function changeButton() {
    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; ++i) {
        key = localStorage.key(i);
        json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
        if(key == json.id) {
            $("#" + json.id).removeClass('btn-custom').addClass('btn-success').empty().html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Added').button('refresh'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe where you think it's breaking. Have you run debugging on what the results of `JSON.parse` are?

Comment: Not sure I get it, but you're checking the localStorage key to see if it matches the `id` inside the JSON for that key? Also, all your variables are global, which is not a good thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you are talking about changing the class name of button if it's id is exist into localStorage stringified object.

If so, first of all you will have to parse the stringified object from localStorage and then you will have to run `for in` loop to check for matching the id of button and object's.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body >
<button id="myName"> my value</button>
</body>

<script>
var obj = {name:'suman', id:'myName', address :'lodhi road'};
localStorage.myobj = JSON.stringify(obj);
var buttonId = "myName";
function changeButton() {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.myobj);
    for(var i in myObj){
        //buttonId is defined above, its depend on you, how you would get on here
        if(myObj[i] == buttonId){
            //alert('success');
            $("#" + json.id).removeClass('btn-custom').addClass('btn-success').empty().html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Added').button('refresh'); 
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", changeButton, false);

</script>
</html>
```